# BootstrapToggle how to prevent change event

Tags: jquery, input

I am using the jquery plugin bootstrapToggle in my web application, and encountered one issue here, my code is like below

```
<input id="toggle-event" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle">
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#toggle-event').change(function() {
       if (some condition) {
                 $('#console-event').bootstrapToggle('toggle');
       }
    })
  })
</script>
```

Basically what I want to do is when some click the checkbox, I will do some check, if condition failed, I will toggle the checkbox to set it back.

The issue here is after checking failed, the checkbox toggle back, and it triggers change event again, and then fall into a dead loop, is there a way to prevent the change event from firing if the condition failed? thanks.

Comment: Please provide some more details i.e. the condition you are applying. Right now I can tell you that you could use e.preventDefault() to stop event propagation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a click handler to the checkbox, do your check in there and call [`preventDefault`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) on the [event](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). This will prevent the default action happending on the checkbox which is checking it and firing the change event.

```
<input id="toggle-event" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle">
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#toggle-event').on("click", function(e) {
       if (some condition) {
          e.preventDefault();
       }
    }).change(function() {
       $('#console-event').bootstrapToggle('toggle');
   })
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

For the [BootstrapToggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) plugin it replaces the standard html checkbox with some fancy `DIV`s to make it look pretty.

So to do this you need to add a click handler on the adjacent `DIV` to the checkbox, something like this

```
<input id="toggle-event" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-style="testtoggle">
$(document).on('click.bs.toggle', 'div.testtoggle', function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation()
    var $checkbox = $(this).sibling('input[type=checkbox]')
    if (some condition) {
            $checkbox.bootstrapToggle('toggle')
    }
})
```

Note the `data-style=".."` attribute on the `input` that we are now targeting in the event and the [`stopImmediatePropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) to prevent the BootstrapToggle default event from firing.

Comment: I have tried to use the click event but not firing, seems it's not propagated to bootstrapToggle

Comment: I have updated my comment with how to handle this with BootstrapToggle.